# performance statistics collection sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-performance

We have a performance test scheduled for 3 hours today and I need to collect performance stats. I am new to this firm and have very short notice.

I am using some realtime performance monitoring tools but not aware of anything that is not heavy and will capture this information for the 3 hours for further analysis. This is for SQL 2005 and is a Vendor application.

Any guidance on what to capture or scripts you can provide would be great. I am not sure how long the information would be retained in the DMV.

Fairly new to sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler is a standard part of the product suite.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/

Comment: Thank you Podiluska. I was considering using it but my understanding is that SQL Profiler can be resource intensive and so I cannot run it for 3 hours...